# How to Calculate Specific Numbers Within a List

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to take specific numbers within a list to calculate them but am not sure where to start. For example if we have a empty list, list = [] and then we call the list in the future with the user input numbers to definition def example(list):. How can I take a1, b1, a2, b2, etc.. from that list? I will need to calculate different calculations with them, so they need to be in the order of a1, b1, a2, b2, etc..

The numbers within the list is undefined until a user inputs how ever many numbers they wish. I will need to use all of the user inputed numbers

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You need list indices. The first element you can call by `list[0]`, second will be `list[1]`, then `list[2]`, `list[3]` etc.

Comment: @Sid, thanks for the assistance! If the amount of numbers within the list is undefined until a user inputs however many numbers they wish, how would I go about doing this with an undefined set of numbers?

Comment: Do you want to preform a calculation on all of the numbers in this list?

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is `def example(*args):`? If the user calls `example(1,2,3)` then `args = (1,2,3)`, and `list(args)` equals `[1,2,3]`. `*` is the "spread operator"

Comment: can you make the question more clear? let say the user enters 6 elements in your list. a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3. do you need all of them? or you want to access a few?

Answer (score 0):

You can call **list[index]** ex: list[0], list[1]
or you can pass through it as a loop

```
for l in list
   print(l)
```

Or you can pass as an argument buy **fun(*list)**